# Getting an Error using AWS S3 when loading an img from the bucket after 1-2h of inactivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I'm new to AWS and I'm using it with my django app in localhost. Since I'm still developing I'm using the free tier S3 bucket.

I display images, user click on a button it show an image from my S3 bucket.

After 1-2h aprx of inactivity (user not clicking any button to display the img hosted in the S3 bucket), I get the following error:

[image]

**GET  403 (FORBIDDEN)**

It gets fixed after I refresh the page, then I can click any button to display any image and it works as it should.

Does anyone know why this happens? I have been googling around for the past few hours and found nothing.

**Does the AWS S3 free tier bucket go to sleep after X minutes of inactivity?**

**UPDATE: URL**

`https://{bucketname}.s3.amazonaws.com/{imagename}.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={credential}&X-Amz-Date=20200505T142015Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature={signature}`

Comment: I noticed you are using s3 presigned url here. Could you extend the expiration time?

Comment: I just added the URL

Comment: Yeah, notice `X-Amz-Expires=3600`. it means the url will only be valid for an hour.

Comment: I have been reading about expiration date and seems it's a way to make a queue for further deletion of old files. Do you know whats the default time for this queue to get deleted? Is there any way to change `X-Amz-Expires=3600`  to 1 day?

Comment: You probably confuse the `X-Amz-Expires` with the expiration set in lifesysle policies. These two are totally different things. The former one is used to control when the generated presigned url will expire, and the latter one determines when the object will be deleted by the lifecycle policies.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

Comment: thanks a lot, I have been reading the doc and there doesn't seem to be any way to increase the `X-Amz-Expires` is it? instead of 1h to 2h i.e

Comment: You can increase this easily in the SDK code that generates this url.